# Network error React(frontend) and Nodejs(backend)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, cors

I am unable to link my frontend(React) and backend(Nodejs) together with Axios as it keeps encountering Network Error (I have also included CORS into my backend application but it still does not work). The backend runs on Postman too but not when integrated with the frontend. Frontend is running at localhost:3000 while backend runs at localhost:5000

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)
```

Here is what my code looks like:
Frontend:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:5000")
.then((res) => {
  console.log(res.data);
  alert("Hi succeedd");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
  alert("Try again");
  });
```

Backend:

```
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
var cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));

//Connect to database
connectDB();

//Init middleware to read data sent in req.body
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("API running"));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: are you sure your localhost is https?
also try to use cors without configuration, so only `cors()`, I am not sure if you give it the right configs.

Comment: As you are accessing backend from  your frontend which is running on `localhost:3000`, you have to give access to this URL in your backend code. Like `allowOrigin or accessURL = 'http://localhost:3000" ` . Then only your Frontend can communicate with your backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you set up proxy in your `package.json` correctly?

you should add this line: `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` so that the it knows to proxy requests between a local frontend and backend

see this for more details: https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-app-with-node-js-server-proxy

Comment: Good to hear, Mark the question correct if you get a moment! Thanks